# it doesn't exit after all the code line passed

Tags: node.js, promise

I am working on node.js.
The code below works but it doesn't exit command in command prompt after all the code is done. see the capture below.

```
   "use strict";
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    
let pool  = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    //password : 'root',
    database : 'dbname'
});

var test = (sql) => {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     pool.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
       resolve(rows);
     });
   });
}

function aaaa(){
  let sql = "select * from dbname.tablename";
  test(sql)
  .then((rows)=>{
    console.log("rows="+Object.entries(rows[0]));
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    console.log("error");
  });
}

aaaa();
```

command prompt:
cursor is still here.
[image]

**update:**
added `pool.end();`.
it did exit the command.
But is it good practice to put this end() there?

```
function aaaa(){
  let sql = "select * from dbname.tablename";
  
  test(sql)
  .then((rows)=>{
    console.log("rows="+Object.entries(rows[0]));

    test(sql)
    .then((rows)=>{
      console.log("rows="+Object.entries(rows[0]));

      pool.end();
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log("error");
    });
  })
  .catch((err)=>{
    console.log("error");
  });
}
```

Comment: close the db connection

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thanks. It worked. I added the update and one more question to the post.

Comment: looks fine, its the only place you can put it

Comment: np, a shameless plug, but if you want to simplify your db workflow check out: https://github.com/lcherone/autorm